# Room temp. sensing in a split AC unit

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a fairly typical "split" air conditioning unit ( LG 1 Ton Inverter Model JS-Q12ATXD, White) in my room.

The remote has a button which shows me the "Room Temp."

What I'm wondering is where it senses this at? Is there a thermocouple in the remote? Or in the indoor unit?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Usually in the indoor unit. They leave the fan on slow so that the sensor has air drawn across it.

Putting the sensor in the remote risks it being left on top of a TV, or in your hand, or another warm place. It could also be left somewhere out of range of the indoor unit.

Comment: Exactly. Makes sense now.